# php (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-graph-api

what should i do to fix this problem this is my code i am using facebook graph API to do it 
     require_once("src/facebook.php"); // set the right path

```
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = '000000000000000';
    $config['secret'] = '0000000000000000000000';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
    // $config['publish_actions'] = true;
    $fb = new Facebook($config);

    $params = array(
      // this is the access token for Fan Page
      "access_token" => "--------------------- my access token --------------------------",
      "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook",
      "link" => "http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php",
      "picture" => "http://i.imgur.com/lHkOsiH.png ",
      "name" => "How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP",
      "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
      "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
    );

    try {
      // 466400200079875 is Facebook id of Fan page https://www.facebook.com/pontikis.net 
      $ret = $fb->api('/417648154966881/feed', 'POST', $params);
      echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Fan Page';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: have you ask permission **publish_stream**

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since years. don´t use it.

Comment: so, are you trying with an app admin/developer or with ANY user?

Answer (score 0):

I have a code with request permission from user... I hope this help.You have use old version with facebook api, I will update preference soon

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
        $config = array('appId' => '000000', 'secret' => '000000', );
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        try
        {
            $user_id = $facebook -> getUser();
            if($user_id){
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            }else {
                      $login_Url = $facebook -> getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1, 'fbconnect' => 0, 'scope' => 'user_about_me,user_activities,user_status,read_stream,publish_stream,photo_upload,status_update,publish_actions','redirect_uri' => 'https://yoururl.com/'));
                      exit("<script>window.top.location.replace('$login_Url');</script>");
            }
        }catch(exception $e){
            /
            exit("<script>location.reload();</script>");
    }
```

update

URL Preference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that **you did not authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission, or you did not authorize the user at all**.

About authorization, check out this page in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Keep in mind that you need a "Page Access Token" to post "as Page", this is explained very well in the following articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Basically, you need to **authorize a user with `publish_actions` AND `manage_pages`** and call `/me/accounts` with the API to get Page Tokens for all the Pages of the user.

...and then there is **"[Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login)"**. Those permissions will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin/Developer/Tester). You need to go through a review process with them before you can release your App to the public.

Of course you have to do the programming part on your own. It´s not that hard though :)